# Как записать такой запрос в Yii2 использую ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

У меня есть такой запрос

```
select * from (SELECT `products`.*, max(product_properties.max_value) as sort 
FROM `products` INNER JOIN `product_properties` ON product_properties.product_id = products.id 
WHERE (`products`.`status`=1 and product_properties.property_id = 429) 
AND (`products`.`company_id` NOT IN (26, 31, 11, 47, 57, 58, 47, 87)) 
AND (`products`.`product_type_id`='3') group by products.id 
ORDER BY `products`.`end_action`, sort desc) tmp 
group by tmp.name, tmp.company_id order by tmp.end_action limit 10
```

Как его можно написать, используя ActiveRecord? У меня просто API и мне нужно именно через ActiveRecord

Comment: Причём тут API и ActiveRecord?

Comment: при том, что у меня для api свои модели, которые наследуют обычные, которые ActiveRecord. в них прописаны правила для вывода полей

Comment: ты имеешь в виду вывод  в DataProvider и GridView?

Comment: я имею ввиду вот такое - http://joxi.ru/MAjqVkKS1aPM82. то что в DataProvider можно передать Yii::$app->db->createCommand() я знаю

Comment: Смотрите документацию, ActiveQuery все это умеет. В конце концов sql можно использовать в findBySql

Comment: я знаю о этих методах, но ума не приложу, как это написать(